# Can't start mongod service on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

I'm running the latest Mongo release build on Ubuntu 16.04.  I can run it with this command:

```
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

but whenever I run it with:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

It exist with a code of 2 (invalid arguments).  This is my mongod configuration in /etc/mongod.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  mode: requireSSL
  PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

I followed the installation instructions and added

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

to

```
/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
```

In the /etc/mongod.conf, if I comment out PEMKeyFile and mode, then mongod does start up with ssl.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `ssl:` section nested under the `net:` section, or it is at the wrong level and hence an invalid argument. Something like:

```
net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```